# Center responsive ratio div

Tags: css

I want to create web app for my home automation system but i have a problem with the img of my house.

What i want is to have center (verticaly and horizontaly) image of my house, responsive and still at the image's ratio.

First i try :

```
body {
        color: #000;
        background: #3A3D50;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .rect {
        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 50%;
        text-align: left;
        background-image: url('http://www.bashihq.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/3d-house-floor-plans-modern-3d-floor-plans-are-also-a-great-way-for-architects-realtors-and-at-house-floor.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center; 
        position:relative;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="rect">
        </div>
    </div
```

Work great but didn't verticaly centered.

So i try to add some absolute positioning :

```
body {
        color: #000;
        background: #3A3D50;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    .rect {
        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 50%;
        text-align: left;
        background-image: url('http://www.bashihq.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/3d-house-floor-plans-modern-3d-floor-plans-are-also-a-great-way-for-architects-realtors-and-at-house-floor.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center; 
        position:relative;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="rect">
        </div>
    </div>
```

But how center .rect into .container ?

Thank a lot.

Edit :

I forget to precise, i need to place div on my image that keep location.

```css
body {
            color: #000;
            background: #3A3D50;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        .container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
        .rect {
            width: 100%;
            height: 0;
            padding-bottom: 50%;
            text-align: left;
            background-image: url('http://www.bashihq.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/3d-house-floor-plans-modern-3d-floor-plans-are-also-a-great-way-for-architects-realtors-and-at-house-floor.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
            background-position: center; 
            position:relative;
            }
    .rect2 {
    width: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 31.5%;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    border-radius: 100px;
        }
        .rect4 {
    width: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 60%;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border-radius: 100px;
        }
    .rect3 {
    width: 50%;
    height:50%;
    background-image: url('images/light.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
        left:32%;
        }
```

**code**

```
<body>
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="rect">
            <div class="rect2"><div class="rect3"></div></div>
            <div class="rect4"><div class="rect3"></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Seeking something like this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/unvshyw8/3) ?

Comment: Thank it works great :)

Comment: i have a new problem, before i could add item on my image with position absolute, so wathever the screen size it was always on the same image location. Now when i add a div inside rect with absolute position, location change with screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform:translate` (CSS3)

**CSS**

```
body {
    color: #000;
    background: #3A3D50;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.rect {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 350px; // Adjust your needs
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-image: url('http://www.bashihq.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/3d-house-floor-plans-modern-3d-floor-plans-are-also-a-great-way-for-architects-realtors-and-at-house-floor.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hLt5rguq/8/)**

Comment: Nice only one problem is image size on my phone landscape

Comment: You can use percent in the height instead a fix height with px.  on the .rect element. Maybe it helps...try height: 150%; - http://jsfiddle.net/hLt5rguq/9/ - Try to adjust your needs.